# What is the recommended Git work flow for class libraries / frameworks?

Tags: git, git-submodules, class-library, git-subtree

The information on submodules and subtree is a bit confusing and often [scornful](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/) and I simply want to know

***What is the best git work flow for class libraries / frameworks***

Both subtree and submodule seem like candidates but some recommend just keeping everything in one repository.

**Scenario**

So I have a WinForm project that uses a specific control, I want to manage that specific control separately, with a test harness but that specific control does need to exist in the main winform project as it will be useful to update/test certain elements "live" (e.g. things that have complex input).

The specific control is based off a more generic control and a framework I have developed, which I want to reuse. The specific control *may* also be reused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the case where the whole "project" needs to be cloned and built (by say a build server), including its "custom class libraries". And sometimes the build servers method is out of your control (i.e. changing the script to clone more then one repo).

In this case the class library has to be "added" to the git repo but you want to **maintain it seperately** in this case I have found "**git subtree**" to be a good solution. However this is where there is some confusion.

If you google "git subtree" you get 2 slightly different results

1. GIT Subtree Merge Workflow
2. git subtree

Now I welcome clarification to this answer, but my feeling is the second has replaced the first by wrapping it up.

The best article I found on how to use git subtree is [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) and there is also a very detailed article on the git subtree merge workflow [here](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/03/16/Managing-Nested-Libraries-Using-the-GIT-Subtree-Merge-Workflow.aspx), they are both compared to **git submodules** in their respective articles if you are interested.

**The summary of how I use this now**

To bring in the latest stable version of my class libary into the main project:

```
pullclasslibrary
```

to push any changes I made to the class library within the main project:

```
pushclasslibrary
```

**How I Got There**

*Note:* It can look daunting but most of it is "set up" and it doesn't take that long

Have two separate repos e.g.:

- path/to/mainproject/.git
- path/to/classlibrary/.git

The aim here is to have "mainproject" contain the latest stable code from "classlibrary"

cd into your main project. ***e.g.*** "cd path/to/mainproject"

Create an easy to use "name" **?1** for your class library

```
git remote add -f <a_remote_name> <your seperately maintained repo>
```

***e.g***

```
git remote add -f my_class_library path/to/classlibrary/.git
```

Now add this as a **subtree**

```
git subtree add --prefix <folder within main proj> <a_remote_name> <branch_in_class_library_you_want_to_track> --squash **?2**
```

***e.g.***

```
git subtree add --prefix source/libraries/class_library my_class_library stable --squash
```

Now we perform a fetch so that your main project is fully aware of the class library and the branch we want to track

```
git fetch <a_remote_name> <branch_in_class_library_you_want_to_track>
```

***e.g.***

```
git fetch my_class_library stable
```

At this point you can just pull and push the **subtree** (library)

```
git subtree pull <folder within main proj> <a_remote_name> <branch_in_class_library_you_want_to_track> --squash
git subtree push <folder within main proj> <a_remote_name> <branch_in_class_library_you_want_to_track> --squash
```

I personally set up a bash alias because that is a lot to type:

***e.g.***

```
alias pullclasslib="git subtree pull --prefix source/libraries/class_library my_class_library stable --squash"
alias pushclasslib="git subtree push --prefix source/libraries/class_library  my_class_library stable --squash"
```

And that's how I got there :)

I have **skipped over some details** here so I highly recommend [reading the first article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)

**Footnotes:**

***?1*** *So we are really creating a "remote" just like "origin" is a remote, a "name" is very much an over-simplification. Git allows you to create as many remotes as you like, and as it turns out to completely different repos. The default "git pull" is usually set to "git pull origin", where origin is the git repo you cloned.*

***?2*** *the --squash is optional, and worth reading up on its own right, but the dirty summary is when you merge with --squash, you dump the commit history. My personal preference is I don't want the rich history of the class library bundled in with my main repo, it wouldn't make sense to me, at most I want one commit saying "pulled latest version of class library". However if I find myself making changes to the class library in the main repo and I want to push that into the class library I do want to push the history into it. However I am currently contemplating squashing that as well as it seems to push all of the commit history for my main repo, which as far as the class library is concerned doesn't make sense. So I would probably stick with the articles suggestion of using "squash" bi-directionally.*

**--UPDATE--**

I changed my mind on the squash, I really wouldn't recommend omitting it for the push, because it will take all of the history from your main repo, which now that I have done it a few times, taints the history of my class library

### I have updated the examples to squash bidirectionally

***stable*** *keep in mind this is **a branch in your class library repo**, most likely you want to track "master" but I wanted to create a clear separation in the examples so I pretended that my class library had a branch called "stable". Apologies if this actually creates more confusion*

Comment: also useful for merging with "their" strategy

alias pullimagetheirs="git pull -s subtree -X theirs ImageControl master"

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use separate git repos whenever possible. Especially if you want to use a CBI Tool like Jenkins. Git-submodules add a lot of complexity. If you are a beginner with git or so are your team members I would strongly suggest not to use submodules.